# Why "waiting on the signatures can block an account"

Tags: transactions

In the explanation about the [long-lived transactions here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/operations.html), they mention that

> waiting on the signatures can block ... an account

and there is a solution proposed, involving a temporary account creation. I tried to find more information about that (for example: does one need to provide a minimum balance to that temporary account) but can't see much so far.

Is there a place where the exact mechanics of the long-lived transaction explained in more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem behind the multi-sig transactions is described in docs:

> Because all transactions are constructed with specific sequence numbers, waiting on the signatures can block Anush’s account.

A transaction contains a specific account sequence number. That's why in case if the source account submits any other transaction, for example a payment, the long-lived transaction becomes invalid as source account sequence has been changed.

The proposed solution (temporary account) implies the following steps:

1. Generate a new key pair for the temporary account.
2. Fund new account. In order to create it you need to send at least 1 XLM to the newly created address. The minimum account balance depends on your goals. Each additional signature, trustline, order, and data entry [requires 0.5 XLM reserve](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance). And do not forget to add at least 0.001 XLM to cover transaction fees. So if you want to make a payment in, say, [EURT](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/EURT-GAP5LETOV6YIE62YAM56STDANPRDO7ZFDBGSNHJQIYGGKSMOZAHOOS2S) secured by multi-sig with 2 additional signers, you'll need to send at least **1+0.5+0.5×2+0.001=2.501XLM**.
3. Create a trustline and send assets, add additional signers to the account if your business logic requires it.
4. Prepare a long-lived transaction on behalf of the temporary account.
5. ...wait for some time...
6. Gather all required signatures if you are using multi-sig.
7. Submit your transaction to network.
8. Merge temporary account back to your main account to release reserved funds (2.5 XLM in our example).